# Threads not excecuting as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to simulate a 400 meters race using multithreading concept.In this application totally 5 groups are created and they are named by country names,each group should have 2 players.First player is allowed to run for the first 200 meters followed by the next player in the group and the winner group has to be announced.Since i am a beginner in multithreading concept i tried to implement the first 200 meters process without concerning the next 200 meters process.But running the code doesnt print anything on the console.please help me to get through this...

**RelayDemo.java**

```
public class RelayDemo implements Runnable
{
    public void race()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
        {
            if(Thread.currentThread().getName()=="rakesh"||Thread.currentThread().getName()=="nathan"||Thread.currentThread().getName()=="max"||Thread.currentThread().getName()=="villiers"||Thread.currentThread().getName()=="decapro")
        {
            System.out.println("The distance covered by"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"is "+i);
        }

    }
}
public void run()
{
    this.race();
}
}
```

**ExcecuteRelay.java**

```
public class ExcecuteRelay {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    RelayDemo r=new RelayDemo();
    ThreadGroup t1=new ThreadGroup("india");
    ThreadGroup t2=new ThreadGroup("australia");
    ThreadGroup t3=new ThreadGroup("usa");
    ThreadGroup t4=new ThreadGroup("africa");
    ThreadGroup t5=new ThreadGroup("france");
    Thread r1=new Thread(t1,r,"rakesh");
    Thread r2=new Thread(t1,r,"kishore");
    Thread r3=new Thread(t2,r,"nathan");
    Thread r4=new Thread(t2,r,"johnson");
    Thread r5=new Thread(t3,r,"max");
    Thread r6=new Thread(t3,r,"tim");
    Thread r7=new Thread(t4,r,"villiers");
    Thread r8=new Thread(t4,r,"duminy");
    Thread r9=new Thread(t5,r,"decapro");
    Thread r10=new Thread(t5,r,"lues");
    r1.start();
    r2.start();
    r3.start();
    r4.start();
    r5.start();
    r6.start();
    r7.start();
    r8.start();
    r9.start();
    r10.start();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: **Thread.currentThread().getName()=="rakesh"** use String.equals !

Comment: @user3493289 using "==" to compare strings is **always** a problem even if it might function in isolated cases.